# I've try Firebase integration in my react native application, I have added rules to the root-level build.gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

build.gradle file :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

App level build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test_push"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-notifications')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the build of the project, I get the error:

```
Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
    For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
    Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:WithDexForDebug
    Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac$zza;
        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac$zza;
          at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

    :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Yes @agent_hunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
```

Changed to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```